# How to extract data after the enrichment in Adobe Campaign(Neolane)

Tags: adobe, extract, neolane

I'd like to extract a list after the enrichment in the workflow in Adobe Campaign(Neolane). However, the data extraction function doesn't work (I have used a local directory) .

Is there any other way to extract data after the enrichment??

For example, can I update the list with enriched content and then export the list?

Thanks a lot for your feedbacks,

Best regards,
Daisy

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the "Extract" node/box. 
You have to specify the extension (.txt ; . csv ; etc...) while naming the file. 
your file is created on A.Campaign's server. You can't export it locally without a SFTP. 
Otherwise, you can export through the export wizard, (see https://docs.campaign.adobe.com/doc/AC/en/PTF_Importing_and_exporting_data_Exporting_data.html)

I hope that you will find this helpful.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a List Update activity where you can hold the data coming out of enrichment activity. Once the LIST is created/updated, you can navigate to profiles & Recipients > LISTS > yourList and export the data.
[image]